# Issues making a random number bubble sort in python

Tags: python, sorting, random, numbers, generator

My dad is trying to get me to learn how to code during quarantine so told me to make a random number bubble sort in python. The user is meant to input if they want to see the numbers from biggest to smallest and vice versa and then create a random number list and sort them. Im a bit stuck and don't know where to go.

Heres the code

```
import random


def bubble_sort(list):
    # We go through the list as many times as there are elements
    for i in range(len(list)):
        # We want the last pair of adjacent elements to be (n-2, n-1)
        for j in range(len(list) - 1):
            if list[j] > list[j+1]:
                # Swap
                list[j], list[j+1] = list[j+1], list[j]





correct=False
upordownuni=False

list = []

for i in range(0,100):
    x = random.randint(1,10)
    list.append(x)


while correct==False:
    print("Do you want the list to be sorted up or down?")
    upordown = input ("Type up or down for what you want\n")
    if upordown==("up"):
        upordownuni=True
        break
        bubble_sort()
    elif upordown==("down"):
            break
            bubble_sort()
    else:
        print("Invalid! Please input up or down.")
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, you do not need that `break`.  I would put the call to `bubblesort()` outside the `if`/`elif` block.  Those two are what jumps out at me.

Update:
Your `bubblesort` function needs a parameter of the list to sort; the function call does not pass that parameter.

In Python `list` should not be used as a variable name as that is a Python reserved word.

Comment: @WOMP do those fix your problem?

Comment: Not quite because i dont know how to filter the sorted list from highest to lowest and vice versa

Comment: At a quick glance your sort looks reasonable.  What happens when you run your program?

Comment: When i try to call on bubble sort, nothing happens

Comment: you should get an error because I now notice that you defined the function to take a parameter, but you did not pass a parameter on you invocation of the function.  Also, you should not use `list` as a variable name as that is a reserved word in python

Comment: ahh alright thanks, I'll try to sort that out later